# Form not passing the values

Tags: php, forms

I am creating a php appointment calendar. I am using the following code to print calender days. Upon clicking on a day, the concerned input values should be passed to a php file. but its not posting. Im getting undefined index variable error. whats wrong with my code.

```
    $calendar.= '<form name="'.$list_day.'" action="touch.php" method="post">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="reg_no" value="'.$reg_no.'" disabled/>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="exe_name" value="'.$exe_name.'" disabled/>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="'.$mobile.'" disabled/>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="company" value="'.$user_data['company'].'" disabled/>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="division" value="'.$user_data['division'].'" disabled/>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="s_date" value="'.$complete_date.'" disabled/> 
                               <div class="day-number1" align="center"> <input name="'.$list_day.'" type="submit" value="'.$list_day.'"/></div>

                        </form>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disabled inputs are not passed. Remove disabled property for your inputs.